AttributeError: '_asyncio.Task' object has no attribute 'is_alive'
Whenever the socket client connect to the the socket server I get the following error:
Client connected:  3uRG6PtVuta3wHsbAAAD
message async handler error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ahmed/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/engineio/async_server.py", line 483, in run_async_handler
    return await self.handlers[event](*args)
  File "/home/ahmed/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/socketio/async_server.py", line 669, in _handle_eio_message
    await self._handle_connect(eio_sid, pkt.namespace, pkt.data)
  File "/home/ahmed/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/socketio/async_server.py", line 552, in _handle_connect
    success = await self._trigger_event(
  File "/home/ahmed/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/socketio/async_server.py", line 638, in _trigger_event
    ret = handler(*args)
  File "/home/ahmed/PycharmProjects/decimal-trade/prices.py", line 27, in connect
    if not thread.is_alive():
AttributeError: '_asyncio.Task' object has no attribute 'is_alive'

The socketio server
from aiohttp import web
from threading import Thread
import socketio
import requests 

sio = socketio.AsyncServer(async_mode='aiohttp', logger=True, engineio_logger=True, cors_allowed_origins='*')
app = web.Application()
sio.attach(app)

thread = Thread()
url = 'https://financialmodelingprep.com/api/v3/stock/real-time-price?apikey=yfmtiz4PGwIlCalGtRjsLcrQ9rF6NAHt'

async def server(request):
    return web.Response(text='Server Running...')

async def getPrices():
    while True:
        data = requests.get(url)
        data = data.json()
        data = data['stockList']
        await sio.emit('stocks', {'data': data}, namespace='/prices')
        await sio.sleep(60)

@sio.on('connect', namespace='/prices')
def connect(sid, environ):
    global thread
    print('Client connected: ', sid)
    if not thread.is_alive():
        thread = sio.start_background_task(getPrices)

@sio.on('disconnect', namespace='/prices')
def disconnect(sid):
    print('Client disconnected: ', sid)

app.router.add_static('/static', 'static')
app.router.add_get('/', server)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    web.run_app(app, host='127.0.0.1', port=8080)

The socket.io-client in react
import { io } from 'socket.io-client';

const URL_ = 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/prices';

export const socket = io.connect(URL_, {
    cors: {
        origin: 'http://127.0.0.1:8080',
        credentials: true,
    }
});


Well, you start by assigning a threading.Thread to the variable, and then you reassign it an asyncio.Task and expect it to keep working like a thread...
For asyncio code like this, you probably shouldn't be using threading at all. I'm not clear what you are trying to achieve with that variable...

How do you reassign it to asyncio.Task?

I have changed thread = Thread() to thread = threading.Thread(). Now, how do I do the asyncio.Task?

I'm not sure you read the comment correctly. How do you expect thread.is_alive() to work if thread is an asyncio.Task? More importantly, what are you even using this variable for? If you explain what you are trying to do, then we can give a better solution. I don't believe you should be using threading at all.

How would you refactor the code? I'm trying to execute the server as a background thread

I need to send a message to a client every second

I have a front-end react client which needs to connect to the back-end server and display the prices.

So, based on you wanting to create a background task to send the requests periodically to all connected clients, the below code should work better.
The approach to create a background task is documented at: https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/web_advanced.html
As we are sending to all connected clients, we don't need to track connection/disconnection events and can remove those hooks.
I've also replaced requests with aiohttp for the network request. Because requests is not async, it would result in blocking your entire server while waiting for the response.
sio = socketio.AsyncServer(async_mode='aiohttp', logger=True, engineio_logger=True, cors_allowed_origins='*')
app = web.Application()
sio.attach(app)

url = 'https://financialmodelingprep.com/api/v3/stock/real-time-price?apikey=yfmtiz4PGwIlCalGtRjsLcrQ9rF6NAHt'

async def server(request):
    return web.Response(text='Server Running...')

async def get_prices():
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as sess:
        while True:
            async with sess.get(url) as resp:
                data = await resp.json()
            await sio.emit('stocks', {'data': data['stockList']}, namespace='/prices')
            await sio.sleep(60)

async def run_prices_loop(_app):
    task = asyncio.create_task(get_prices())

    yield

    task.cancel()
    with contextlib.suppress(asyncio.CancelledError):
        await task  # Ensure any exceptions etc. are raised.

app.router.add_static('/static', 'static')
app.router.add_get('/', server)
app.cleanup_ctx.append(run_prices_loop)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    web.run_app(app, host='127.0.0.1', port=8080)


Excellent. However, I'm getting the following error n1sIZGf6FWNfFjZgAAAB: Sending packet MESSAGE data 4/prices,"Unable to connect", this is on the client side, ```const URL_ = 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/prices';
export const socket = io.connect(URL_, {
cors: {
origin: 'http://127.0.0.1:8080',
credentials: true,
}
});```

I have used socket.io-client as the client side library.

I'm not familiar with socketio, only aiohttp. You haven't created a /prices endpoint on the aiohttp app. Is it expected that the sio app will auto-create it or otherwise handle it?

At a quick glance at the docs, maybe you need to create an event and have the clients enter a room: https://python-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/server.html#rooms

I think it could work if we create a route for /prices in the aiohttp app. I believe for predefined connections, namespaces are preferred. I have changed the apikey to a working one 73u8FPMOvsTiyJytPUIxmr15AWaQj3VR.

Have you figured out a working solution?

Again, I'm not familiar with socketio, I'm not here to do you work for you. :P
